# Notification manager is not working in count down timer class in android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am using a countdown timer class and in the onfinish() state of that class I am creating a notification. Here is the Onfinish method's code:

```
public void onFinish() {
            notificate();
            Log.i("Aler Resume", "Finished");
            remtime.setText("0 : 00 : 00");
            textCondition.setText(getString(R.string.BuddyAlertExpired));
              }
```

In the notificate() method I wrote:

```
private void notificate() {
        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  

        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New E-mail", System.currentTimeMillis());  

         PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlertResume.class), 0); 
         note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Buddy Alert", getString(R.string.BuddyAlertExpired), intent); 
         note.defaults= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
         note.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
         notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note); 


    }
```

Its working fine when I keep my application open. But when I go back from the application the onfinish method is being called and I can see the log correctly but the notofication method is not working and doesnt show any notification. Is there any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go away from the app, It can happen that Android think your process running of the CountDown Timer as an Spam or Extra and not-intended. and Finish it of..(Like it think you forgot to close let me close)

So better Use AlarmManager for the above stuff like to set PendingIntent - Notification,AT THE TIME WHERE YOU START YOUR COUNT-DOWN TIMER ALSO SET NOTIFICATION WITH PENDING INTENT USING ALARM MANAGER.

```
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Test", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent intentTL = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Test", "Do something!",
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentTL,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(1, notification);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pendingIntent);
```